# Find Jordan decomposition constructed by function.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

$$
F(x) =\left\{
 \begin{array}{l l}
  0   && x \leq 0\\
  1-x  && 0 \leq x \leq 1\\ 
  2x-4 && 1 < x \leq 2 \\
                1 && 2 < x
 \end{array}
\right.
$$

The question is which set can be taken as $X^+$ and $X^-$ in Hahn decomposition?

---

> I know that $X=X^++X^-$. Here $X^+$ increases and $X^-$ decreases. So plotting the graph I have [image]
>
> and $$
> X^+ =\left\{
>  \begin{array}{l l}
>   0   && x \leq 1\\ 
>   2x-4 && 1 < x \leq 2 \\
>                 1 && 2 < x
>  \end{array}
> \right.
> $$
>
> $$
> X^- =\left\{
>  \begin{array}{l l}
>   0  && x \leq 0\\ 
>   1-x && 0 < x \leq 1\\
>                 0 && 1 < x
>  \end{array}
> \right.
> $$

What have I missed?

Comment: I've just fixed up the notation on your piece-wise functions. Hope you don't mind!

Comment: @SamuelYusim thanks a lot